# $E(x)=\sqrt{\cos^{4}(x)+m\cdot\sin^{2}(x)}+\sqrt{\sin^{4}(x)+m\cdot\cos^{2}(x)}$ is constant for $m=?$

Tags: trigonometry

The values of $m$ such that $E(x)$ is constant.

$$E(x)=\sqrt{\cos^{4}(x)+m\cdot\sin^{2}(x)}+\sqrt{\sin^{4}(x)+m\cdot\cos^{2}(x)}$$

I tried to take this expression as a function then to find it's derivative and to equalize it with 0 but I didn't get too far.Also, I tried squaring but I got heavy calculations.Some ideas?

Comment: Have you tried $$m=0$$?

Comment: $m=0$ is a rather trivial solution, and it doesn't necessarily ensure that it is the only value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $E(x)$ is a constant, $E(0)=E(\pi/4)$.

\begin{align*}
1+\sqrt{m}&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{m}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{m}{2}}\\
1+2\sqrt{m}+m&=1+2m\\
2\sqrt{m}&=m\\
m&=0 \quad\textrm{or}\quad 4
\end{align*}

When $m=0$, $E(x)=1$ for all $x$.

When $m=4$,

\begin{align*}
E(x)&=\sqrt{\cos^{4}x+4\sin^{2}x}+\sqrt{\sin^{4}x+4\cos^{2}x}\\
&=\sqrt{(1-\sin^2x)^2+4\sin^2x}+\sqrt{(1-\cos^2x)^2+4\cos^2x}\\
&=(1+\sin^2x)+(1+\cos^2x)\\
&=3
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your help, sir!

Comment: Just one question.Why E(0)=E(pi/4)?

Comment: If E is constant then for any x E have same value, right ?

Comment: $E(x)$ is a constant. So for whatever $x$, $E(x)$ is just the same.

Comment: Yes, thank you again:)